# Can I assign a reserved IP to Azure Function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

A third-party company requires us to work from a certain IP address. But can an Azure Function can be assigned a reserved IP (outgoing)?

Comment: Not something you probably want to do when running a Consumption plan. Might be feasible when using the App Service Plan. I'd suggest taking a look into API Management, which can act as a reverse-proxy for this (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/api-management/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to provide your own IP.

For Consumption Plan, it's also not trivial to get the IP range provided by Azure, because they might change over time. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50531916/1171619) for more details.